# Remove Duplicate Objects in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, comparator

All,

I have a object

```
public class Device {

     public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public String getDeviceId() {
        return deviceId;
    }

}
```

I get all the List of Values

```
     List<Device> uList = getList();
```

In the List i have a duplicate values Based on **userId** Now i want to get Unique list which will remove the duplicates of **userId**

How can i acheive it, I am very much new to Java

Comment: What if the userid is the same, and the device id is different? There's a couple answers here regardless, one more correct than other. Additionally you might benefit from a different design depending on how you're using this list (show the code for that)

Comment: That's fine We need to consider only userid

Comment: It's quicker not to put the duplicates in there in the first place. Consider a `HashSet` or `TreeSet`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way is to create a `Map` where the key is the `userId`:

```
Map<String, Device> map = new HashMap<>();
devices.forEach(d -> map.put(d.getUserId(), d));
List<Device> uniques = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
```

Or, using streams:

```
Map<String, Device> map = devices.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Device::getUserId, d -> d, (a, b) -> a));
List<Device> uniques = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
```

Alternatively, you can dump them in a `TreeSet` with a comparator that checks `userId`:

```
Set<Device> set = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Device::getUserId));
set.addAll(devices);
List<Device> uniques = new ArrayList<>(set);
```

All of this assumes you're not concerned about discrepancies in `deviceId`. Otherwise, take a look at [`Map.merge()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) or the corresponding [`Collectors.toMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) overload.

Comment: HashMap is the simplest & most efficient (O(N)) solution. +1

Comment: It's safe to assume that insertion order matters if the original question used a List. TreeSet works on comparison order. LinkedHashSet will handle uniqueness and insertion order.

Answer (score 0):

Define equality in your object by overriding equals and hashCode (why hashCode? read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java)) and then use a Set (or a LinkedHashSet if order matters) rather than a List.

```
    public class Device {

        // fields, constructors, getters, setters
        ...

        @Override
        public boolean equals(final Object obj) {

            if (obj == this)
                return true;

            if (!(obj instanceof Device))
                return false;

            return Objects.equals(userId, ((Device) obj).userId);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {

            return Objects.hash(userId);
        }
    }
```

If you absolutely must have a List at the end of this... well it's easy enough to manipulate.

```
final Set<Device> uniqueOrderedDevices = Sets.newLinkedHashSet(devicesList);
final List<Device> list = Lists.newArrayList(uniqueOrderedDevices);
```